# tengo un inconveniente con Python

Tags: python

El tema es que hice un script en python2.7 con el uso de BeatifulSoup...
el script es el siguiente:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


from Wappalyzer import WebPage, Wappalyzer

def main():
    wap = Wappalyzer.latest()
    try:
        web = WebPage.new_from_url("https//:example.com")
        tecnologias = wap.analyze(web)
        for t in tecnologias:
            print("tecnologia detectada: {}".format(t))
    except:
        print("Ha ocurrido un error!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("saliendo")
```

al ir a la terminal (estoy usando linux) me da el siguiente mensaje de error:

> $python wappalyzer.py 
>   /home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py:114:
>   UserWarning: You are using a very old release of Beautiful Soup, last
>   updated in 2011. If you installed the 'beautifulsoup' package through
>   pip, you should know the 'beautifulsoup' package name is about to be
>   reclaimed by a more recent version of Beautiful Soup which is
>   incompatible with this version.
>
> This will happen at some point after January 1, 2021.
>
> If you just started this project, this is easy to fix. Install the
>   'beautifulsoup4' package instead of 'beautifulsoup' and start using
>   Beautiful Soup 4.
>
> If this is an existing project that depends on Beautiful Soup 3, the
>   project maintainer (potentially you) needs to start the process of
>   migrating to Beautiful Soup 4. This should be a relatively easy part
>   of the Python 3 migration.
>
> """)

El curso que hago esta basado en python2, si me pueden explicar como puedo pasar el codigo a python3 o como solucionar unicamente este problema

Answer (score 1):

Para ocultar el `UserWarning` podes usar el siguiente código antes de importar
`Wappalyzer`:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, module="Wappalyzer")
```

Pero esa sólo es una solución temporal. El verdadero problema es que Python 2.7
[va a ser descontinuado en el 2020](https://pythonclock.org/). La mayoría de las librerias van a
dejar de dar actualizaciones para Python2.7. Deberías aprender Python3,
en especial, las diferencias con Python2.7.

En este caso, tu código no es incompatible con Python3 (aunque algunas cosas
tienen significados distintos), así que podés usarlo como tal pero con Python3.

Como el módulo que usas es para Python2.7, necesitas otro que soporte Python3.
[Acá](https://github.com/chorsley/python-Wappalyzer) hay un fork de Wappalyzer que con una pequeña modificación puede
funcionar en Python3.

Primero clonamos el módulo con *git*:

```
$ git clone "https://github.com/chorsley/python-Wappalyzer.git"
```

Luego en el archivo `./python-Wappalyzer/Wappalyzer/__init__.py` hay que cambiar:

```
from Wappalyzer import WebPage, Wappalyzer
```

Por:

```
from .Wappalyzer import WebPage, Wappalyzer
```

Y podés instalarlo con:

```
$ pip3 install ./python-Wappalyzer
```